# How to set a filter for a specific filetype in Windows 7 index search?

Tags: windows-7, windows, search

I want to do a full text search within RTF files that have a different file extension than *.rtf.

I have set a new file type in the "Advanced Options" of the Windows "Index Options". But I can't select the "Rich-Text-Filter" for my added file type.

[image: Windows Index Options]

How can you set the Rich-Text-Filter for other filet types than *.rtf?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set other file extensions for IFilters with [SearchFilterView v1.00](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_filter_view.html) freeware from Nirsoft.